# How can I make my status bar be the same colour as my navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I want my navigation bar to look similar to that of the Twitter app. My app only has three different views, so I don't mind doing each one manually. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view, put it where the status bar will be, and set its background color to which ever color you prefer.

```
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame)
statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() // Replace with color you desire
self.view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm actually doing it in Swift. Do I even need to do anything programatically? Or can I do it right in the attributes inspector?